# How does one test generic collections in nunit?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

How can I do something like this in NUnit?

```
class Foo
{
    int Value { get; set; }
    ...
}
...
ICollection<Foo> someFoos = GetSomeFoos();
Expect(List.Map(someFoos).Property("Value"), Has.Some.EqualTo(7));
```

`List.Map()` only accepts `ICollection`, not `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could convert your `ICollection<T>` to something that implements `ICollection`. Array for instance:

```
ICollection<Foo> someFoos = GetSomeFoos();
var array = new Foo[10];
someFoos.CopyTo(array);
Expect(List.Map(array).Property("Value"), Has.Some.EqualTo(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you could conceptually use linq to objects extensions, something like:

Expect(someAs.Count(), Has.Some.EqualTo(7));

Comment: I'm not trying to test the number of elements in someFoos, but that some elements have the property Value equal to 7.

Comment: Ok, that was just an example.  You could just as easily use a different extension, such as the Any operator.
someAs.Any(a=>a.Value == 7)

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried something like this instead:

```
List<Foo> someFoos = GetSomeFoos();
```

as `List<T>` *does* implement the `ICollection` interface.